# QtCreator and OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, qt-creator

I managed to compile successfuly programs that use OpenCV with QtCreator but i have a problem with the dlls when i try to execute my application.

[image]

This is the error i get. The wierd thing is that i don't have this dll in my system.
I tried to download it and place it in the same directory with the executable but i get the same error.

here is my .pro file

```
LIBS += -Lc:/Users/Libraries/OpenCV2.3/build/x86/mingw/bin/

LIBS += -lopencv_calib3d230 \
        -lopencv_contrib230\
        -lopencv_core230 \
        -lopencv_features2d230 \
        -lopencv_flann230 \
        -lopencv_gpu230 \
        -lopencv_highgui230 \
        -lopencv_imgproc230 \
        -lopencv_legacy230 \
        -lopencv_ml230 \
        -lopencv_objdetect230 \
        -lopencv_video230

INCLUDEPATH += c:/Users/Libraries/OpenCV2.3/build/include/

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
```

Anyone that knows why this problem occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was going wrong. 
I compiled opencv again and changed my .pro file to link from that folder.

Linking with the opencv-superpack package that is provided for windows caused this problem.

I hope this will help others facing the same problem.

Comment: I'd be grateful if you could provide a walkthrough for installing this on win32 with mingw and msys

Comment: Are you facing the same problem? The solution for me was straight forward. I had to compile opencv from sources cause the version of my compiler was not the same with the dll provided with the superpack. If you are using QtCreator just use the .pro file from the 1st post.

Comment: That is an excellent tip, I didn't see the .pro file there. However I helped myself into some cmake and here's the success story for anyone interested in the future: http://voidpage.blogspot.com/2011/09/building-opencv-on-win32-with-mingw-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you try, instead of simply putting the dll in the folder to add it to the path of your system ?

On win XP it's something like:
Configuration Panel > System > Advanced > Paths

Answer (score 0):

Downloading a versioned DLL probably won't work. libstdc++-6.dll should be in the bin directory of your MinGW installation (which was probably included with QtCreator, check there).

You must distribute this dll with your app (or link with `-static`) or at least add its directory to PATH.

Comment: I found somewhere that i can use `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -static` but the result is the same. I 've downloaded the superpack wich has the dlls already built. Can this thing be responsible for the problem? If they are built with msvc i don't think they should work with mingw.

Comment: If you're going static, everything needs to be static(ally linked to runtime libraries). Just ship the DLL, nothing wrong with that. Copy the libstdc++ DLL to the same directory your app is in, and presto.

Comment: I 've installed the sdk again and now i have this dll. I copied the dll to the folder where the exe is and i get the same error.